# How do I enable the deploy to visual studio app center task in my build pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, visual-studio-app-center

I created a pipeline to test publish my hello UWP application.
My build pipeline contains a task Deploy to Visual Studio App Center.

[image: deploy tasj]

No errors are indicated in my settings.
How do I enable the deploy task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like each task, right click on the task and "Enable selected task(s)":

[image]

The result:

[image]